# How to jump to another know page on a button click?

Tags: redirection, 7

I need to implement a select list (something like auto-complete in JQuery UI) with a `Go` button on a mini-panel (or block). I can do this in Javascript. When the user selects a value, a corresponding page (for example: article) URL is computed.

Assuming we know the URL of that page, how do I get Drupal to jump to that page when the user clicks on the `Go` button? I am no expert in PHP, but could implement some if necessary, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole implementation (including the URL computing) is done on the client side with javascript then the easiest solution would be to simply use code like the following:

```
$('#go_button_id').click(function() {
  location.href = 'url_to_the_computed_page';
});
```

On the server side you could use Drupal's [block hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7) and [form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to create a block with a simple form and then use `$form_state['redirect'] = 'url_to_the_computed_page';` in the form submission handler for the redirect.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was thinking the same since everything was on the client side.